# Can looking up object parameter in a large object array take too long? (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I'm making a 2d tile-based game. Some of my testing levels have few tiles, some have 500,000 for testing purposes. Running a performance profiler that comes with visual studio shows the bottleneck:
[image: the image must be here, it shows how <code>if (blocks[i].Visible)</code> takes 87% of time]

What is exact reason why it takes so much time? How do I avoid such situations?

**UPD:** nevermind, I'm just going through the whole array instead of going only through the ~200 visible tiles.

Comment: The object lookup is a simple calculation, the slow-down is likely in your `.Visible` call.

Comment: try adding a local variable var block = blocks[i]; to see if that is in fact taking up all the time.

Comment: Also, what type of collection is blocks?  Some collection types are slower than others, especially in C#.

Comment: You should look at implementing a Quadtree for your scenes. This will help to quickly identify the blocks that should be rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that evaluating each individual Visibility property/field would take much time - it's that you are doing it 500k times - it adds up. Since this is what the profiler estimates is the bottleneck, it means that the vast majority of items have `Visibility` set to false - otherwise you would assume the `Draw()` method call would be shown as bottleneck. One approach to optimize this could be separating the visible items and only iterating over those.

Comment: Oops, I totally forgot to change the loop to check only those tiles which are within visibility range, not that whole array :x That's the reason.

Answer (score 2):

.Visible is a property. To understand why this is a bottleneck, you need to look at the implementation of that getter. While it looks like just a simple Boolean, it could be complicated behind the scenes.

Comment: It's simple enough, the method checks if the coordinates of each tile are within the visible area of the viewport and sets `Visible` to true or otherwise. My guess is it's going through the array which takes long.

Comment: @user1306322 could you update the question with the `Visible` getter code? (mainly, cause I'm curious, but someone might be able to speed it up)

Comment: @user1306322: You can do much better than that, though.  Group your tiles into zones of the world.  You can still draw more than one zone at once (for seamless motion), but you'll only need to check adjacent zones, not the whole universe.

Comment: Well of course, you're doing it 500k times. You could use an array or something else instead, where the index corresponds to the coordinates. That way, the visible tiles can be directly accessed instead of having to check all of them.

Comment: Time it with StopWatch. If it is actually taking too long, then optimize it. Otherwise, move on.

Answer (score 1):

Is 500k a typical scenario? Keep in mind that depending on your real world needs, the complexity varies a lot.

If you really have to deal with 500k tiles, I'd have a second List of visible tiles, or a list of ints that contain the array indexes of those visible tiles.

Answer (score 1):

A sequential check for finding objects with a certain property turned on means a worst case scenario of running 'n' iterations where 'n' is the total number of records. This is certainly a bottleneck.

You may want to keep a collection of visible items separately.